# Calculating double integral with gamma incomplete function in R

Tags: r, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I need to calculate a double integral on two variables (B0 and B1) in R.
Till now, nothing complicated with the `int2` function.

But, my function to integrate includes gamma incomplete function (`gammainc` in R ) !

The following error message appears :

```
 Error in gammainc(1/eta, lambda * exp(B0 + B1 * z_arm) * tmax^eta) : 
  Arguments must be of length 1; function is not vectorized.
```

Any advice to help me ?

```
 tmax = 5
 Sig = matrix ( c(0.2, 0, 0, 0.4) , ncol = 2 )
 Mu  = matrix ( c(1, 0) , ncol = 1 )
 eta = 0.5
 lambda = 0.8
 z_arm = c(rep(0.5,10), rep(1,15))


 to.integrate = function(B0, B1)
  {

   first.int =  1/eta *(lambda * exp(B0 + B1 * z_arm))^(-1/eta)* gammainc(1/eta, lambda * exp(B0 + B1 * z_arm)*tmax^eta)['lowinc']
   B = matrix(c(B0, B1), ncol=1)
   multi.norm = 1 / (2 * pi * det(Sig)^(1/2)) * exp (- 0.5 * t( B - Mu ) * solve(Sig) * ( B - Mu ) )

   return (first.int * multi.norm)

   }


 int2(to.integrate , a=c(-Inf,-Inf), b=c(Inf,Inf), eps=1.0e-6, max=16, d=5)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you tried wrapping gammainc with Vectorize? `Vectorize(gammainc)`